# rename the variables in an array with names from another array

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to rename the variables based on one array elements in the folloing way,

```
%let var= class name gender;

data want; 
set have;

%global noof; 

array point(*)$   %str(&var)  ;
a=dim(point);
call symputx('noof',a);


array newvar(&noof);


do i=1 to &noof;

newvar(i)=translate(point(i),',','.');

end; 

drop &var; 

do i=1 to &noof;

rename newvar(i)=vname(point(i));

end;
```

run;

I want to rename the new variables to the first array elemets.

LOG:

```
 rename newvar(i)=vname(point(i));
                  -
                  22
                  76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: -, :, =.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Comment: You cannot use functions in a RENAME statement. Before you start using macro variables or macro code to generate SAS code write out the SAS code you want to generate.  Show us what SAS code you are trying to generate.

Comment: I think the title says exactly what he wants - he wants to rename the variables in an array with names from another array.  The code inside the data step is superfluous to the question.

Comment: @DomPazz ya you are right., i think I will change the question.

Comment: Go vote on my new enhancement request on sascommunities site. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/Enhanced-RENAME-syntax-to-handle-variable-lists/idi-p/401758#M2799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the value on the RHS of the `RENAME` statement must be a literal.  The statement is evaluated at compile time, not run time.

Try this:

```
%let var= class name gender;

%macro translate(datain,dataout,vars);
%local n i var;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&vars));


data &dataout(rename=(
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        %let var = %scan(&vars,&i);
        newvar&i = &var
    %end;
)); 
set &datain;

array invars(&n) $  &vars  ;

array newvar(&n) $;


do i=1 to &n;
    newvar(i)=translate(invars(i),',','.');
end; 

drop &vars i; 

run;
%mend;

data test;
class = "1,2,3";
name= "Dom,Pazzula";
gender="M";
run;

%translate(test,out,&var);
```

You can run into issues if the length of these character variables are too large.  The new variables might be truncated.  You will have to modify this to add a `length` statement.

Comment: This works, i understand, renaming at the output dataset level.

Comment: The syntax in this post works because it generates the full list of old=new pairs of variables to rename. That will work in both a regular RENAME statement or by using the RENAME= dataset option on the output dataset.